# Reload Script Accessed On Another Website

Tags: javascript, php, updates

I'm trying to create a script that runs and updates real time(semi if needed) on another website.

The back bone of this is a php script which accesses a database on my server. From there it outputs some basic variable information.

So we're on the same page. This is the script itself.

> Located on www.A.com-->

```
<?php 
include "includes/db_conx.php"; 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($productCount > 0) {
    $x=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $url = $row["url"];
             $status = $row["status"];
             $headerCode = $row["headerCode"];
             $bodyCode = $row["bodyCode"];   
             if($status == "Ready") {
                $statClass = "greenBox";
             }
             if($status == "Live") {
                $statClass = "yellowBox";
             }
            if ($status == "Hold") 
                $statClass = "blueBox";

             $lastEdit = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["lastEdit"]));
             $x++; 
             $bgChange = ($x%2 == 0)? '': 'blackRow';

$product_list .= "<div class='row noMargin $bgChange'><div class='boxMini idColDeveloper'>$id</div><div class='boxMini statusColDeveloper $statClass boldDiv twelveFont' style='margin:4px;'>$status</div><div class='boxMini urlColDeveloper'>$url</div><div class='boxMini' id='postDateDeveloper'>$lastEdit</div><div class='boxMini actionColDeveloper'><div style='float:left;'> <a href='bodyCodes_edit.php?pid=$id'>Edit</a></div><div style='float:left;margin-left:12px;'><a href='bodyCodes_creator.php?deleteid=$id'><img src='https://www..com/upload/images/delete-item.png' alt='delete' style='display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;'/></a></div></div><div class='clear'></div></div>";
$list = $product_list;
    }

}

      echo ("document.getElementById('date-holder').innerHTML = '".addslashes($list)."';"); 


?>
```

On an entirely different website and server I'm using this code to display the information from my database at www.A.com:

> Located on www.B.com-->

```
<script src="https://www..com/test/test.php"></script>
```

Is there any way to update this every second or less? So it's something of a real time output.

Comment: Any help with language to help in research would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: I haven't received any comment yet as normally would occur. If someone can help me to format this question in another way that I may receive response, please let me know.